# Sorting multiple html tables logically related to each other

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sorttable.js

I wish to sort 3 separate tables that are logically related to each other but kept separate in design for some purpose.
I am using sorttable.js for sorting.
Can someone guide me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear on what you are trying to achieve: do you mean, sort all 3 tables separately (looks like it does this out of the box) or sort all the data but keep the design / structure of the 3 tables (meaning that potentially rows may be moved between tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the sorttable.js library (version 2) to accomplish my task of sorting multiple tables that are separated by design but related to each other.I have applied the sorting for the first table and other two tables get sorted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just add marked class attribute to the table - class="sortable".

More deitals: http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/02/sort-table-rows-using-ajax.html

Comment: I know that, but I have 3 tables related to each other and want to sort them all based on a single column from table1.

Comment: Why you would like to do this? It sounds like a search and not a sort.

Comment: Which sorttable.js version are you using? I found two version [here](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable) sorttable.js or sorttable_v1.js?